# Из битов в байты

Tags: c#, типы-данных, конвертация

Есть массив битов:

```
Int32[] val = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
BitArray t = new BitArray(val);
```

из расчета **1 байт** = **8 бит** я рассчитываю получить 1 байт после конвертации битов в байты.

Как правильно конвертировать биты в байты?

UPD
Нашел код:

```
BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(new bool[] { true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false});
            byte[] bb = new byte[1];
            bitArray.CopyTo(bb, 0);
```

возвращает байт = [3].

```
 int[] bits2 = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            BitArray bitArray2 = new BitArray(bits2);
            byte[] bb2 = new byte[1];
            bitArray2.CopyTo(bb2, 0);
```

возвращает ошибку.

Мне нужно сделать как   в статье на [википедии](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)):

> This method can be used to pad messages which are any number of bits
>   long, not necessarily a whole number of bytes long. For example, a
>   message of 23 bits that is padded with 9 bits in order to fill a
>   32-bit block:
>
> ... | 1011 1001 1101 0100 0010 011**1 0000 0000** |

В примере мы добавляем к 23ем битам  9 бит до 32битов.
Соответственно, в моем случае нужно добавить не 9 бит а 8 (**1000 0000**). Я не пойму, каким способом мне это сделать. У меня массив из 8 байт, заполнено 6. В 7ой байт мне нужно добавить {100000000} (в битах),а 8ой - {000000000} (в битах).

**Как правильно это сделать?**

Comment: Есть [такое](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560123/convert-from-bitarray-to-byte) решение на английском stackoverflow.

Comment: не подходит, я все там перепробовал

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конструктор `BitArray`, который принимает целые числа, интерпретирует их не как биты, а как 32-битные значения. Чтобы преобразовать массив целых в `BitArray`, нужно предварительно конвертировать массив целых в массив булевых значений:

```
int[] bits = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
var arr = new BitArray(bits.Select(i => i != 0).ToArray());
```

Если же вам нужен именно `byte`, а не `BitArray`, то формула следующая:

```
byte b = (byte)((bits[0] << 7)
              | (bits[1] << 6)
              | (bits[2] << 5)
              | (bits[3] << 4)
              | (bits[4] << 3)
              | (bits[5] << 2)
              | (bits[6] << 1)
              | (bits[7] << 0));
```

Comment: зачем вы в примере получали var arr?

Comment: @LeonardBertone Из вопроса неясно, что именно вам надо: получить `byte` или получить `BitArray`. Поэтому решений два. Если вам нужен только `byte`, то код с `BitArray` вам не нужен.

Comment: Я обновил тему, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @LeonardBertone Э... `bytes[6] = 0x80; bytes[7] = 0x00`?

Answer (score 2):

посмотрите пример (ваш случай Base=2):
[Convert.ToByte Method (String, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
      string value = "11";
      byte number;
      number = Convert.ToByte(value, 2);
      Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);
```

вот посмотрите этот примерчик, для понимания padding:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    short CRC_raw = 0x421F;
    byte CRC_high;
    byte CRC_low;
    short CRC_rebuilt;

    Console.WriteLine("    Raw: " + ToHex(CRC_raw) + " -- " + ToBinary(CRC_raw));

    CRC_low = (byte)(CRC_raw & (short)0x00FF);
    CRC_high = (byte)(CRC_raw >> 8);

    Console.WriteLine("    Low: " + ToHex(CRC_low) + " -- " + ToBinary(CRC_low));
    Console.WriteLine("   High: " + ToHex(CRC_high) + " -- " + ToBinary(CRC_high));

    CRC_rebuilt = (short)(((0x0000 | CRC_high) << 8) | CRC_low);

    Console.WriteLine("Rebuilt: " + ToHex(CRC_rebuilt) + " -- " + ToBinary(CRC_rebuilt));
}

static string ToHex(int val)
{
    return "0x" + val.ToString("X");
}

static string ToBinary(int val)
{
    return Convert.ToString(val, 2);
}
```

вот эти операторы вам понадобятся:
[<< Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w.aspx)
[>> Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt18et0d.aspx)

Comment: Я обновил тему, посмотрите пожалуйста